# iTunes 12.5.1.21 on Windows 10 Version 1607 cannot detect iPhone 6s and iPod Touch (5th Generation)

Tags: itunes, windows, ipod-touch, iphone

I have an iPhone 6s and iPod Nano 5th generation which I use with a Dell PC (15R 5521) running Windows 10 version 1607 (updated to the latest version).

The latest version of iTunes (12.5.1.21) is installed but it does not detect either of the devices.

I have tried reinstalling iTunes (doesn't work), trying to update drivers for iPhone and iPod (from Device Manager, doesn't do anything).

Any help or suggestions because I'm at a loss.

Thanks!

Comment: did you uninstall/install or just run it over the top of the old version? Sometimes it takes a 'clean' install to get it to work, using one of the uninstaller apps like Revo

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows 10 N or KN, try installing the latest version of the "Media Feature Pack".

The latest version at present for Windows 10 v. 1607 is the Aug 2, 2016 version, which you can [download here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3133719).